# Autoincrement by set amount in dataframe with mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm attempting to build a simple scheduler using UNIX timestamps and arbitrary rows with lubridate and dplyr, with a pre-set number of rows (100) and an arbitrary auto-increment amount. I can't figure out for the life of me how to implement it, though; in PHP it would be relatively simple using a for-loop.

```
thedate <- as.Date(Sys.Date())
day1fromnow <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(thedate + days(1)))
day8fromnow <- as.numeric(as.POSIXct(thedate + days(8)))
difftime <- (day8fromnow - day1fromnow)/100
```

Thus, with the desired number of rows (100) arbitrarily defined, I get an autoincrement amount of 6048.

If I have this dataframe of 100 rows, the goal is to have this output:

```
Text|UNIXTime
Test1|1568419200
Test2|1568425248
Test3|1568431296
```

What's the best choice here? Assign df$UNIXTime[[1]] the initial value and then mutate with lag? Is there something more obvious and easier?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `seq` to create sequence between `day1fromnow` to `day8fromnow` with a fixed step of `difftime`. We create a `Text` column using `paste0` which will have an auto-incrementing number for every row.

```
data.frame(Text = paste0("Text",1:101), 
           UNIXTime = seq(day1fromnow, day8fromnow, difftime))

#       Text   UNIXTime
#1     Text1 1568419200
#2     Text2 1568425248
#3     Text3 1568431296
#4     Text4 1568437344
#5     Text5 1568443392
#6     Text6 1568449440
#....
```

Note here that that if we create a sequence from `day1fromnow` to `day8fromnow` with steps of `difftime` it gives us 101 enteries including the last one at `day8fromnow`. If we need exact 100 rows we may remove any one entry.